# If we have a relation such that $a\cdot b^2=b^2\cdot a$, then we can say $a\cdot b\cdot b=b\cdot b\cdot a$, then can we say $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$?

Tags: group-theory

I was studying about group theory.

I have a general query regarding it. There was a property called the cancellation property:

If we have $a\cdot b=c\cdot b$, where $a,b,c,d \in G$,
then $a=c$.

Now, if we have a relation such that $a\cdot b^2=b^2\cdot a$, then we can say $a\cdot b\cdot b=b\cdot b\cdot a$, then can we say $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$?

Comment: No. For example, in $S_3$, $a=(123)$ abd $b=(12)$, we have $ab^2=b^2a$, but $ab\neq ba$. Note that to go from $ac=bc$ to $a=b$, we multiply by $c^{-1}$ on the right. No similar cancellation can be done from $abb=bba$ to get $ab=ba$.

Comment: @Thanks a lot! I do get it now ...Thank you!...

Comment: The cancellation property is a consequence of the existence of inverses. If I have $ab=ac$ then I can multiply both sides on the left by $a^{-1}$ then the $a$ will cancel leaving us with $b=c$. However with $ab^2=b^2a$ multiplying on the left by an inverse gives us the relation $b^2=a^{-1}b^2a$ rather than $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be nonabelian and $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\neq ba$ and $b^2=e$. Then $ab^2=b^2a$ (because $a=ae=ea=a$) but, by hypothesis, we cannot have $ab=ba$.

The group @ArturoMagidin gave is the smallest counterexample. Another way to look at $S_3$ is to think of it as the group $D_3$ of symmetries of an equilateral triangle. The element $(123)$ of $S_3$ corresponds to a rotation $\rho$ of $2\pi/3$ radians about the centre of the triangle, while $(12)$ is a flip $\sigma$ about a line of symmetry. It is clear, then, to see that $\rho\sigma\neq \sigma \rho$ (as a composition of symmetries), while

$$\rho\sigma^2=\sigma^2\rho.$$

Indeed, $S_3$ and $D_3$ are *isomorphic*.

Comment: Another good example for this is the quaternion group of order $8$ where we have $ab^2 = b^2a$ for any choice of elements $a$ and $b$. But the group is not abelian.